# Is the largest prime number known? If yes then show. If no then prove.

Tags: prime-numbers

I am not sure whether is known or not, I supposed not but don'nt know how to prove.

Comment: have you tried factoring?

Comment: The largest prime number is not known, nor can it be known, for there are an infinite number of primes. No infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ possesses a maximal element.

Comment: That's a weirdly worded question.  If there were a largest prime and we didn't know it, how on earth would we prove it wasn't known?

Comment: How can you even prove that something is not known?

Answer (score 2):

There is no largest prime, as was shown in Euclid's *Elements*.

If you have a finite list of primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n,$ then the number $p_1 p_2 \ldots p_n+1$ is not divisible by any of those primes, so it must be a new prime or divisible by a new prime.  So there must be infinitely many primes, and therefore no largest prime.

Answer (score 0):

The largest known prime number is $2^{74,207,281} − 1$.  It is a Mersene prime, and it was discovered in January.

Comment: But there are bigger (as yet unknown) primes

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: This doesnot answer the question.